# Validation and training loss per batch and epoch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am using Pytorch to run some deep learning models. I am currently keeping track of training and validation loss per epoch, which is pretty standard. However, what is the best way of going about keeping track of training and validation loss per batch/iteration?

For training loss, I could just keep a list of the loss after each training loop. But, validation loss is calculated after a whole epoch, so I’m not sure how to go about the validation loss per batch. The only thing I can think of is to run the whole validation step after each training batch and keeping track of those, but that seems overkill and a lot of computation.

For example, the training is like this:

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

```
running_loss = 0.0
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
    inputs, labels = data

    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward + backward + optimize
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    # print statistics
    running_loss += loss.item()
```

And for validation loss:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = net(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        # validation loss
        batch_loss = error(outputs.float(), labels.long()).item()
        loss_test += batch_loss
    loss_test /= len(testloader)
```

The validation loss/test part is done per epoch. I’m looking for a way to get the validation loss per batch, which is my point above.

Any tips?

Comment: If you could attach your code of training loop, It'd have been much clearer.

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah Added some code similar to mine. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I've already attached an answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're right that's the way to do it "run the whole validation step after each training batch and keeping track of those" and also as you've thought it's pretty time-consuming and would be overkill. However, If that's something you really need then there's a way you can do it.

What you can do is, let's say you've got 1000 batches in your data. Now to calculate per batch validation loss you can choose not to run the validation step for each of the batches (then you'd have to do it 1000 times!) but for a small subset of those batches, let's say 50/100 (choose as you please or find feasible).

Now, you can use some statistical power so that your calculation for 50/100 batches becomes very very close to that of 1000 batches (meaning this validation loss for a small number of batches must be close to that of 1000 batches if you had calculated that), so to achieve it you can introduce some randomness in your batch selection.
This means you randomly select 100 batches from your 1000 batches for which you'll run the validation step.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Doesn't seem to be any other way. Trying this, but will keep this open still in case someone has another way. If not, I'll select this answer in a few days.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I'd love to see some other approaches as well.

Answer (score 3):

An *epoch* is the process of making the model go through the entire training set - which is, generally, divided into batches. Also, it tends to be shuffled. The validation set, on the other hand is used to tune the hyper-parameters of your training and find out what's your model's behavior towards new data. In that respect, to me, evaluating at `epoch=1/2` doesn't make much sense. Because the question is - whatever the performance on the evaluation set at `epoch=1/2` - what can you do about it? Since, you don't know which data it has been going through in the first half of the epoch, there's no way to take advantage of 'a first half being better'... And remember your data will likely be shuffled into batches.

Therefore, I would stick with the classic approach: train on the entire set then, and only then, evaluate on another set. In some cases, you won't even allow yourself to evaluate once per epoch, because of the computation time. Instead you would evaluate every *n* epochs. But then again it will depend on your dataset size, your sampling from that dataset, the batch size, and the computation cost.

For the training loss, you can keep track of its value *per*-update-step *vs.* *per*-epoch. This will give you much more control over whether or not your model is learning independently from the validation phase.

---

*Edit* - As an alternative for not having to run the entire evaluation set per train batch you could do the following: shuffle your validation and set the same batch size as your trainset.

- `len(trainset)//batch_size` is the number of updates per epoch
- `len(validset)//batch_size` is the number of allowed evaluation per epoch
- Every `len(trainset)//len(validset)` train updates you can evaluate on `1`
  batch

This allows you to get a feedback `len(trainset)//len(validset)` times per epoch.

If you set your train/valid ratio as `0.1`, then `len(validset)=0.1*len(trainset)`, that's *ten* partial evaluations per epoch.

Comment: Agree with all that you've said. This isn't about hyperparameter tuning per se, I'm already using the epoch wise validation loss to do that as you mentioned. This is a tangential observation that I'm trying to make regarding the losses and it would just be nicer to have some more granularity of the loss by training samples/batches instead of whole epochs. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Understood, I've edited my question with what could be an alternative solution.